# jquery set focus on element in next div

Tags: jquery, focus

I'm trying to set the focus on a textarea element when clicking on the headline link. 
this is the HTML:

```
<h2 class="trigger active"><a href="#" id="">header</a></h2>
<div class="toggle_container" style="display:block;">
    <div class="block" id="1">
        <div>Blah</div>

        <textarea name="VALUE">Blah blah</textarea>

    </div>
</div>
```

How can I relatively target the Textarea when clicking the H2?

I prepared a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/MkePe/3/

Any help appreciated..

UPDATE:
There was already a working solution, but when there are DIVs that don't exactly have the right content, everything breaks down. The get(0) method produces a JS error if there's no Textarea. Is there a flexible solution that keeps this in mind as well? Here's the non-working-fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3AbHY/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your modified Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/3AbHY/2/)

In the h2 click handler :

```
$(this).next().find('textarea').focus();
```

Comment: hi! just found out that your solution requires a TEXTAREA in every div which isn't provided by my HTML content. see http://jsfiddle.net/3AbHY/3/

Comment: Okey then .. so how would you like the script to behave in such a case ?

Comment: Thanks! Well, it should just set the focus on Textareas, if there's no "fucusable" Element, it should not throw an error. I got an JS error which broke the whole script because get(0) didnt refer to an object in these cases:
"Cannot convert 
'$(this).next(".toggle_container").slideToggle("slow")
.find('textarea').get(0)' 
to object"

Comment: Sure ... you can cache the jQ object and test if it matched any element `var $ta = $(this).next().find('textarea'); if($ta.length){$ta.get(0).focus();}`

Answer (score 1):

By adding an ID to the TextArea like this `id="toFocusArea"`, you HTML becomes:

```
<h2 class="trigger active"><a href="#" id="">header</a></h2>
<div class="toggle_container" style="display:block;">
    <div class="block" id="1">
        <div>Blah</div>

        <textarea name="VALUE" id="toFocusArea">Blah blah</textarea>

    </div>
</div>
```

And the click event handler would be just using [focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) directly on the TextArea:

```
$("#toFocusArea").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

check:

http://jsfiddle.net/MkePe/4/

You have to load after your document is ready.